# is it possible to use a method from a different class within the same assembly?

Tags: c#, class, .net-assembly

I am new to c#. I am curious if I can do something like this:

```
namespace Test {
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static double someMethod()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        someMethod();
    } 
}
```

I tried something similar to this and it gave me a "does not exist in current context" error. I tried referring it as SomeClass.someMethod() but still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

if the method is  [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/79b3xss3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you are able to call it the following way `SomeClass.someMethod()`

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public void anotherMethod () 
    {
        SomeClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

If you want to class contains methods and fields of other class you should use [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static double someMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
public class AnotherClass : SomeClass
{

}
```

Comment: @d1du What exactly do you want me to explain? about static method or about inheritance?

Comment: Why is it necessary to call someMethod() within a method of AnotherClass? Why can't I just call someMethod() without it being in the body of another method?

Comment: @d1du Every method should be called from a method.  Application starts with Main method and then main method calls other methods, which call others and so on.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx